# Phantom heading entry and display issue in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I am using Microsoft Word and there is a phantom heading role at the end of the navigation pane. Usually, it is just an extra empty row with header style applied. However, it is not exactly the case here.

I uploaded a [video](https://streamable.com/5vluo2) to explain what I am experiencing:

- To start with, I have enabled all formatting marks.
- 00:00-00:15, I checked that all concerned paragraphs have the same style applied (see the highlighted style in the Style pane at the top)
- 00:15-00:17, You can clearly see the extra row and the phantom entry in the navigation pane.
- 00:23-00:38, I checked that all rows are put under the correct heading. Strangely, you can see that as my cursor is placed at the last empty row, the navigation pane has the previous header highlighted, instead of the phantom entry.
- 00:40-00:50, I placed the cursor at the end of the previous row and pressed <kbd>del</kbd>. It is expected that the last empty row would disappear and the phantom entry should be gone. However, instead, the phantom entry remained and the second last heading entry disappeared.

I have no idea what issue is there causing these exceptional behaviors... Can anyone explain?

---

I don't know what information is needed... please let me know if there is anything I should supplement:

- OS: Windows 10 (OS Build 19041.867)
- Word: Version 2103 (Build 13901.20336 Click-to-Run)

Comment: Could you save the file with the problem on DropBox or OreDrive and post a share link here.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Word Paragraphs to break the text into paragraphs but so called Manual Line Breaks. Effectively Word then treats all text as 1 paragraph so that's why everything is a header.

Either manually or with find replace-special you can replace them.

Comment: Not really the issue... I have paragraph break and line break alternating between lines on purpose, and the headers including everything (including those after the line break) are intended. These do not explain my questions.

Comment: After hhh is a manual line break and another after that. This means that they form 1 header paragraph with hhh.  Just remove that last manual line break

Comment: This does not work... The original headers remain in the navigation pane.